# FIFO matching of 2 datasets in tsql: convert from "while" loop to set based logic or CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, common-table-expression

To improve performance, is there a way I can convert the following "while" loop code into a CTE or set-based operation? The code matches two datasets on a FIFO basis, and returns a third dataset with all the matched records.

The records in the datasets represent accounting transactions, which are tracked with an Account ID. The first dataset represents payment received (and adjustments to payments received) in respect of an Account ID. The second dataset represents payments made (and adjustments to payments made) in respect of an Account ID. The records in the two datasets that have the same Account ID need to be matched on a FIFO basis.

**Description of code:**

Start with the first record in each dataset. Iterate through these steps until there are no records remaining in one of the datasets:

1. For the current record in each dataset, compare the Account IDs.
2. If the Account IDs are not equal:

   - For the dataset with the smaller Account ID, move to the next record, and return to Step 1.
3. If the Account IDs are equal, add a record to the FIFO matched dataset

   - The FIFO amount equals the smaller of the dataset 1 amount and dataset 2 amount
   - For the dataset with the smaller amount, move to the next record in the dataset when returning to Step 1

     - If the amounts from both datasets are equal, then this applies to both datasets
   - For the dataset with the larger amount, do not move to the next record in the dataset. Instead, reduce the amount for the current record by the FIFO amount, and use the remaining amount when returning to Step 1

**Sample Inputs & Outputs**

*Input Dataset 1*

| t1_id | t1_acct | t1_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | -2 |
| 4 | 2 | -3 |
| 5 | 2 | 10 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |

*Input Dataset 2*

| t2_id | t2_acct | t2_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 10 |
| 3 | 2 | -2 |
| 4 | 2 | -3 |
| 5 | 2 | -2 |
| 6 | 2 | 11 |

*Resulting FIFO Matched Dataset*

| fifo_id | t1_id | t1_acct | t1_amount | t2_id | t2_acct | t2_amount | fifo_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 10 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | -2 | 3 | 2 | -2 | -2 |
| 5 | 4 | 2 | -3 | 4 | 2 | -3 | -3 |
| 6 | 5 | 2 | 10 | 5 | 2 | -2 | -2 |
| 7 | 5 | 2 | 12 | 6 | 2 | 11 | 11 |

**Existing Code using While Loop**

```
---- BEGIN CODE ----


-- First Dataset
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t1;
CREATE TABLE #t1 (
    t1_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    t1_acct INT,
    t1_amount DECIMAL(19,2) -- Note: amounts can be negative!
);

-- Second Dataset
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t2;
CREATE TABLE #t2 (
    t2_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    t2_acct INT,
    t2_amount DECIMAL(19,2) -- Note: amounts can be negative!
);

-- FIFO matching of First Dataset to Second Dataset where Account IDs values are equal
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #fifo;
CREATE TABLE #fifo (
    fifo_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    t1_id INT,
    t1_acct INT,
    t1_remaining DECIMAL(19,2),
    t2_id INT,
    t2_acct INT,
    t2_remaining DECIMAL(19,2),
    fifo_amount DECIMAL(19,2)
);

-- Sample values for First Dataset. Note: we can assume that these are pre-sorted by Account ID
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES
(1,3),  (1,5),
(2,-2), (2,-3), (2,10),
(3,1);

-- Sample values for Second Dataset. Note: we can assume that these are pre-sorted by Account ID
INSERT INTO #t2 VALUES
(1,5),  (1,10),
(2,-2), (2,-3), (2,-2), (2,11);

-- Variables needed for While loop
DECLARE
    @c1 INT, -- counter to loop through First Dataset; represents the current record from First Dataset
    @c2 INT, -- counter to loop through Second Dataset; represents the current record from Second Dataset
    @t1_acct INT, -- represents the Account ID from the current record from First Dataset
    @t2_acct INT, -- represents the Account ID from the current record from Second Dataset
    @t1_remaining DECIMAL(19,2), -- represents the current remaining amount from First Dataset
    @t2_remaining DECIMAL(19,2); -- represents the current remaining amount from Second Dataset

-- Primer: set counters to 1, i.e. first row
SELECT @c1 = MIN(t1_id) FROM #t1;
SELECT @c2 = MIN(t2_id) FROM #t2;

-- Primer: set Account IDs and current remaining amounts to the values and amounts from the first row
SELECT 
    @t1_acct = t1_acct,
    @t1_remaining = t1_amount
FROM #t1 WHERE t1_id = @c1;

SELECT 
    @t2_acct = t2_acct,
    @t2_remaining = t2_amount
FROM #t2 WHERE t2_id = @c2;

-- Loop through First Dataset and Second Dataset until there are no remaining records in one of the datasets
WHILE @c1 <= (SELECT MAX(t1_id) FROM #t1) OR @c2 <= (SELECT MAX(t2_id) FROM #t2)
BEGIN

    -- Check to see if Account ID from First Dataset current record equals Account ID from Second Dataset current record
    
    -- If Account ID from First Dataset is less than Account ID from Second Dataset, then move on to the next record from First Dataset and update Account ID and remaining amount
    IF @t1_acct < @t2_acct
    BEGIN
        SET @c1 += 1;

        SELECT 
            @t1_acct = t1_acct,
            @t1_remaining = t1_amount
        FROM #t1 WHERE t1_id = @c1;
    END

    -- If Account ID from Second Dataset is less than Account ID from First Dataset, then move on to the next record from Second Dataset and update Account ID and remaining amount
    IF @t2_acct < @t1_acct
    BEGIN
        SET @c2 += 1;

        SELECT 
            @t2_acct = t2_acct,
            @t2_remaining = t2_amount
        FROM #t2 WHERE t2_id = @c2;
    END

    -- Join the current record from the First Dataset to the current record from the Second Dataset, and insert resulting FIFO match into the FIFO Dataset
    INSERT INTO #fifo
    SELECT
        t1_id, -- ID from the current record from the First Dataset
        @t1_acct, -- current Account ID value from the First Dataset
        @t1_remaining, -- current remaining amount from the First Dataset
        t2_id, -- ID from the current record from the Second Dataset
        @t2_acct, -- current Account ID value from the Second Dataset
        @t2_remaining, -- current remaining amount from the Second Dataset
        CASE -- FIFO matched amount is the smaller remaining amount from the First Dataset and Second Dataset
            WHEN @t1_remaining < @t2_remaining THEN @t1_remaining 
            ELSE @t2_remaining 
        END AS fifo_amount
    FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM #t1 WHERE t1_id = @c1) s -- current record from the First Dataset
    JOIN 
        (SELECT * FROM #t2 WHERE t2_id = @c2) u -- join to the current record from the Second Dataset
        ON 1 = 1;

    -- Update variables needed for the While loop
    
    -- If the First Dataset remaining amount was smaller than the Second Dataset remaining amount
    IF @t1_remaining < @t2_remaining
    BEGIN
        -- Second Dataset: Reduce the remaining amount for the current record in the Second Dataset
        SET @t2_remaining -= @t1_remaining;

        -- First Dataset: Move on to the next record and update Account ID and remaining amount
        SET @c1 += 1;
        SELECT 
            @t1_acct = t1_acct,
            @t1_remaining = t1_amount
        FROM #t1 WHERE t1_id = @c1;
    END
    -- If the Second Dataset remaining amount was smaller than the First Dataset remaining amount
    ELSE IF @t1_remaining > @t2_remaining
    BEGIN
        -- First Dataset: Reduce the remaining amount for the current record in the First Dataset
        SET @t1_remaining -= @t2_remaining;

        -- Second Dataset: Move on to the next record and update Account ID and remaining amount
        SET @c2 += 1;
        SELECT 
            @t2_acct = t2_acct,
            @t2_remaining = t2_amount
        FROM #t2 WHERE t2_id = @c2;
    END
    -- If the First Dataset remaining amount and Second Dataset remaining amount are equal
    ELSE IF @t1_remaining = @t2_remaining
    BEGIN
        -- First Dataset and Second Dataset: Move on to the next record and update Account ID and remaining amount
        SET @c1 += 1;
        SET @c2 += 1;
        SELECT 
            @t1_acct = t1_acct,
            @t1_remaining = t1_amount
        FROM #t1 WHERE t1_id = @c1;

        SELECT 
            @t2_acct = t2_acct,
            @t2_remaining = t2_amount
        FROM #t2 WHERE t2_id = @c2;
    END

END;

-- Display the result
SELECT * FROM #fifo;


---- END CODE ----
```

Comment: Cripes that's a lot of code. Suggest you supply just the sample data and the expected results you need and a clear explanation of the logic.

Comment: @Stu Thanks for the feedback. I updated the post to include a description of the code. There is sample data in the beginning of the code, and executing the code returns the expected results. Should I put the inputs & expected results somewhere else in the post?

Comment: Have a look at [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks @Stu! I updated the post. Is that better? Appreciate your help and patience here.

Comment: It may help to describe the problem using real-world terms instead of just an abstraction of abstract "reference values" and "amounts". What do the values really represent. What is the problem that the code is trying to solve. What is the meaning of the results.  This might us better understand the intent and may allow someone here to refactor/restate the problem in terms that might be better suited for set operations.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TN. I updated the post to include some additional context.

Comment: I do not think this can be done as a set operation. The most obvious approach would be to calculate running sums and start/end values for each transaction, and then match overlapping ranges between the data sources. (This would be done after partitioning the data by account number.)  However, I believe that this approach only works with strictly ascending sums, so it would not work when negative adjustment amounts are involved.  If performance is the issue, I suggest that you move the logic to a more suitable high level programming environment.

Comment: Thanks @TN - Appreciate you taking the time to review the logic in detail

Comment: For reference, [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vQBI5Cll) shows the cumulative-sum / overlap approach. It works for acct = 1 and (added data) acct = 4, but does not work with the negative amounts for acct = 2.  Theoretically, your original algorithm *could* be adapted to a recursive CTE that simulates your loop, but you would need to pass your working values from one step to the next as CTE column data, and the result would be something that would be very difficult to understand and even more difficult for someone who comes after you to maintain. I would recommend against even trying it.

Comment: @TN Thanks again for taking the time to put together that example. I'm in agreement with everything you mentioned and posted. I was hoping there was a solution that I was missing, but unfortunately, seems like not. I appreciate your help here.